# Code reverting after for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with the following code. When I click on a link I should only be able to see the corresponding section. By adding in alerts I see that the script is hiding the right elements, but after the loop is ran everything is back to normal. Also, if I change the onClick events to onMouseOver, the hidden elements are kept hidden after the loop has finished.

```
<html>

<head>
<script>

function switchTabs(clicked)
{
    var tab = clicked.innerHTML;
            var content = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

    for(var i=0; i<content.length; i++)
    {
        if(content[i].id && content[i].id.indexOf(tab) !=  -1)
        {
            content[i].style.display = 'inline';
        }
        else
        {
            content[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='' onClick='switchTabs(this);'>Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href='' onClick='switchTabs(this);'>Ajax</a></li>
        <li><a href='' onClick='switchTabs(this);'>PHP</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id='JavascriptSection'>
    <h1>Javascript Section</h1>
</section>

<section id='AjaxSection'>
    <h1>AJAX Section</h1>
</section>

<section id='PHPSection'>
    <h1>PHP Section</h1>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: I think instead of "display" you want "block" to make things visible.

Comment: thank you, although that does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your "onclick" attributes to:

```
<a href='' onClick='return switchTabs(this);'>Javascript</a>
```

and add

```
 return false;
```

to the end of the function. By doing that, you prevent the default behavior of the `<a>` tag from happening.

(You'll also want to use "block" instead of "display" to make sections visible, as I noted in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Add return false and also give a proper href. What was happening was that the page was reloading everytime because of the hyperlinks default action. Also notice this will only work for the first time as the second time the other sections won't be available for id comparisson.

```
<html>

<head>
<script>

function switchTabs(clicked)
{
    var tab = clicked.innerHTML;
            var content = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

    for(var i=0; i<content.length; i++)
    {
        if(content[i].id && content[i].id.indexOf(tab) !=  -1)
        {
            content[i].style.display = 'display';
        }
        else
        {
            content[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    return false;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#' onClick='switchTabs(this);'>Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' onClick='switchTabs(this);'>Ajax</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' onClick='switchTabs(this);'>PHP</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id='JavascriptSection'>
    <h1>Javascript Section</h1>
</section>

<section id='AjaxSection'>
    <h1>AJAX Section</h1>
</section>

<section id='PHPSection'>
    <h1>PHP Section</h1>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of default behaviors.